# displaying async data's property in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I got the following sample code, if I use:

```
 <p>{{usr[0]}}</p>
```

works, but if I refer to title, I got a 'unncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined':

```
 <p>{{usr[0].title}}</p>
```

ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

[a sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ysbvmjtu/)

what is the right way to handle this case? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to use a `v-if` to determine whether to render to the content.

```html
<p v-if="usr[0]">{{usr[0].title}}</p>
```

```js
const TodoList = {
  data() {
    return {
      usr: []
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    let rslt = await response.json();
    this.usr = rslt
  }
}
const app = Vue.createApp(TodoList)
app.mount('#myapp')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<!-- page content -->
<div id="myapp">
  <p v-if="usr[0]">{{usr[0].title}}</p>
</div>
```

You can also use another variable to track whether the content is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Initially your array is empty and there's no property called `title` in the item at index 0 of your array, so you could add some conditional rendering like :

```
 <p>{{usr.length && usr[0].title}}</p>
```